# Proof of Prime Maker Conjecture

Tags: number-theory, algorithms, prime-numbers

In my mind the following conjecture is true:

**Prime Maker Conjecture**

I call a number $n$ *factor-resistant* to $q$ if $q\not\mid n$. Considering $n$ as a composite number, the idea is to make $n$ factor-resistant to all of its (prime) factors. When we multiply a number minus or plus $1$ with one of its (prime) factor and then add or subtract 1, the number would become factor-resistant to that (prime) factor.

The Algorithm:

1. Let $n=m\mp 1$ ($m$ is even).
2. Perform a primility test on $n$, if $n$ is prime output Prime and exit.
3. Find the smallest prime factor $d_0$ of $n$
4. Set $m = d_0 \times m$.
5. Set $n= m \pm 1$
6. Go to Step 2

**Example**

We choose $m=541\#$ ($\#$ is primorial sign) and positive side.

1. $n=541\#+1$
2. $IsPrime(n)$  ? $n$ is composite
3. $d_0=2879$
4. $m = 2879 \times 541\#$
5. $n= m +1$
6. $IsPrime(n)  ? n$ is composite
7. $d_0=342085039$
8. $m=342085039\times 2879 \times 541\#$
9. $n = m + 1$
10. $IsPrime(n)  ? n$ is prime.

Of course the most time consuming step in the algorithm is finding the (smallest) factor, sometimes it makes the algorithm impractical but for a math proof we can think of it as a fast operation.

My conjecture is that, the number of required iterations of this algorithm to convert a composite number to prime one, is finite, but I have no idea how to prove it or even approach it ...

**Update**

I've just made the algorithm more clear.

**More Samples**

- $n = 1549 \times 57179\times 102932777 \times 67118797 \times 718049 \times 8466769 \times 4261711 \times 1444603 \times 100! + 1$
- $n = 18593 \times 3119\# + 1$ is a 1327 digits prime
- $n = 1732043 \times 142981 \times 97787 \times 376001 \times 7933\# + 1$ is a 3423 digits prime

Comment: In step 4 of the algorithm, do you mean to multiply $m$ by $d_0$? Or did you mean $n$?

Comment: And what do you mean by $p_{100}$ in your example?

Comment: To multiply $m$ by $d_0$ and put the result $+1$ into $n$. It is primorial of 100th prime.

Comment: But $d_0$ is not a prime factor of $m$.  So you can't apply the statement about "When we multiply a number with its smallest prime factor and then add or subtract 1..."

Comment: $d_0$ is a prime factor of $n$ or $m+1$, so $d_0 \mid m+1$, and so then we have $d_0 \not\mid d_0\times m + 1$. Got it?

Comment: Yes, sure,  $d_0$ doesn't divide $d_0m +1$ anyway, regardless.  It's just not what you seemed to be saying the algorithm would do, which is presumably why Johan thought you meant $n$ rather than $m$.

Answer (score 2):

Your algorithm does not converge as it is described.

Example: $m = 24$. Choose "+1" throughout.
Then initially $n = 25$.

1. $n$ is composite
2. $d_0 = 5$
3. $n$ becomes $121$
4. $n$ is composite
5. $d_0 = 11$
6. $n$ becomes $265$
7. $n$ is composite
8. $d_0 = 5$
9. $n$ becomes $121$

and so on.

Your example on the other hand updates the number $m$ in each step. Is that what you have in mind?

Comment: No, he just explained it poorly. See his example - third $n$ should be $11 \times 5 \times 24 + 1$. I did a little testing and found that this way at least first 96 integers work.

Comment: @Hans Engler, I've updated the algorithm with correct explaination

Answer (score 1):

For a better counter-example, see Broadhurst's answer on http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/primenumbers/message/25024